# Как решить такую задачу в Wordpress'e?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть 3 страницы wordpress:

http://107.170.21.244/wp2/?page_id=4

http://107.170.21.244/wp2/?p=7

http://107.170.21.244/wp2/?p=1

Задача - нужно написать, в файле functions.php, функцию, которая от зависимости от GET параметра выводит различное содержимое на этих страницах. Надеюсь описал все доступно.

Comment: Нет, не доступно. Расскажите, что Вы *на самом деле* хотите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у тебя и есть 3 разных GET запроса, даже по-умолчанию должно показывать разные записи или страницы, без дописывания чего-то в functions.php

Comment: Могу предположить, что вопрошающему надо смаршрутизировать обращения к `/wp2/?page_id=X` на `functions.php`. Но ваш ответ уже принят, и это странно (ведь он не решает авторскую задачу, а просто констатирует факт).